How to find impulse response for the given difference equation?
$$y[n]-\frac{5}{2}y[n-1]+y[n-2]=x[n]-x[n-1]$$
I am trying to find the impulse response of this discrete-time system in time domain. Of course I need equations but a little help with the insight on all these equations, reasons of them etc. would be great. Here is what I've done:
Since I am concerned with the impulse response, I need the solution for zero-state response, in which all initial conditions are set to $0$. First, I solve for the homogeneous equation to find the characteristic modes of the system.
$$\gamma_1 = 1/2 \\ \gamma_2 = 2$$
Thus, homogeneous solution is found to be:
$$y_h[n]=(c_1 2^{-n} + c_2 2^n)u[n]$$
I actually don't know why I put that $u[n]$ next to the solution. The original problem just states LTI system and gives the difference equation. It solves by Z transform but I really don't know what makes us put that step signal there. As far as I know LTI system does not imply causality
(Edit: Since the question actually asks for all possible values for the system's impulse response, depending on ROC it applies inverse Z transform and gets $u[n]$ accordingly. But if we are working on time domain, is this the correct way to approach the question? First using $u[n]$ and changing accordingly after that)
Using the method of undetermined coefficients, I suggest that $A_0\delta[n] + B_0\delta[n-1]$ is a particular/forced solution for this difference equation.
When I substitute that suggested forced solution into the system equation, as far as I could, it did not yield a consistent system of equations. In the following question (How to find impulse response for the given system?), it was solved in a similar manner but the substitution was done for the whole solution and not only for the forced solution. It is usually done by plugging in only the forced solution in the method of undetermined coefficients. I know that the equation must hold for both cases but for the given question in the link and for this question it does not give a consistent set of equations.
I thought that maybe since we have $u[n]$ next to the "original" homogeneous solution, the part left for forced response might also take into account that and also have some components inside that homogeneous solution with $u[n]$ attached and that is why we need to use the whole solution. I am just making random comments I can say.
For this question, I tried to substitute the whole solution into the system equation but it was not really good looking. I tried using MATLAB but probably also failed at it.
In short:

Why are we multiplying the homogeneous equation by $u[n]$? Does the question have anything that implies it?
Why did we substitute the whole solution and not only the forced solution for the question in the link? Why doesn't it work the way that it is usually done, by substituting only the forced solution?
How to solve this question, following the way I did? How to solve it in time domain more practically?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

First of all it's important to realize that the given difference equation (DE) doesn't uniquely describe a single system. It describes three different systems, one of which is causal, another one is anti-causal, and the third one has a  double-sided (non-causal) impulse response.
If we're looking for the impulse response of the corresponding causal system, we know that $h[n]=0$ for $n<0$, and the component of the impulse response corresponding to the homogeneous solution can be multiplied by the step sequence $u[n]$. But the general homogeneous solution of the given DE is still
$$y_h[n]=c_12^{-n}+c_22^n\tag{1}$$
(without $u[n]$).
Your guess of the particular solution doesn't work, because the method of undetermined coefficients only works for a rather small class of forcing sequences, like exponentials and polynomials.
Let's now assume we're looking for the impulse response of the causal system described by the given DE.
We can make the following guess for the impulse response:
$$h[n]=y_h[n]u[n]\tag{2}$$
In general, $(2)$ will not work because of the "disturbance" of the solution caused by the right-hand side of the DE. The most general form of the impulse response is
$$h[n]=\sum_{k=0}^{M-N}A_k\delta[n-k]+y_h[n]u[n],\qquad M\ge N\tag{3}$$
where $M$ and $N$ are the maximum delays of the input and the output sequences, respectively. I.e., in $(3)$ we assume a DE of the form
$$\sum_{k=0}^Na_ky[n-k]=\sum_{k=0}^Mb_kx[n-k]\tag{4}$$
Since in the given problem we have $N>M$, the guess $(2)$ will work. We just need to determine the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ in $(1)$ by computing the first two values of the impulse response by iteration and equating these values with $(2)$.
EDIT:
This is to show that we could also have used the educated guess
$$h[n]=A_0\delta[n]+y_h[n]u[n]\tag{4}$$
with $y_h[n]$ given by $(1)$, in case we were not sure whether $h[n]$ contains an extra impulse at $n=0$. Plugging $(4)$ into the DE gives
$$A_0\delta[n]+y_h[n]u[n]-\frac52A_0\delta[n-1]-\frac52y_h[n-1]u[n-1]+\ldots \\A_0\delta[n-2]+y_h[n-2]u[n-2]=\delta[n]-\delta[n-1]\tag{5}$$
Now consider $n=2$. Since for $n=2$ all delayed components of the homogeneous solution are "switched on", $(5)$ evaluated at $n=2$ becomes
$$A_0+y_h[2]-\frac52y_h[1]+y_h[0]=0\tag{6}$$
and we can conclude $A_0=0$ because by definition of the homogeneous solution we have
$$y_h[n]-\frac52y_h[n-1]+y_h[n-2]=0,\quad\forall n.$$

Thank you. As far as I understand, since the maximum delay, which probably corresponds to the degree, of the output is higher than that of the input, we won't have any impulse terms in the impulse response. At this point, the linked question's answer seems relatable to me. In that answer, the complete solution was assumed to have an impulse and was plugged into the system equation. In the end, it didn't have an impulse but we did get a consistent system of equations. Is this because the total solution was substituted? I wasn't able to substitute the total response but would it hold?

Moreover, I can't really see a difference between the two. Both impulse responses have only $y_h[n]u[n]$ or $y_h(t)u(t)$. By the inspection you mentioned about $M$ and $N$, we could easily say the CT impulse response has no impulses. However, we tried something very similar to undetermined coefficients and it worked. That's not how I generally see it applied but it worked that way. Should we even not try to handle the question that way and immediately look for $M$ and $N$ inspection?

Lastly, hopefully, I don't understand why it wouldn't work if we only plug in forced solution. In the end, it works for plugging in total solution since presumed forced solution is $0$. Why isn't it found to be $0$ when it is solely substituted in the system equation? Thank you so much.

@LarsSmith: If you plugged $h[n]=A_0\delta[n]+(c_12^{-n}+c_22^n)u[n]$ in the DE with $x[n]=\delta[n]$ you'd get $A_0=0$, just like in the CT case. Both ways are fine, but of course it's smarter to know in advance if there will be impulses or not; in that case you have fewer unknowns to start with. Concerning your last question, what is the "forced solution"? Note that neither $A_0\delta[n]$ nor $A_0\delta[n]+A_1\delta[n-1]$ are solutions to the DE.

We make an educated guess like "an impulse could be a forced solution to this DE" and then we substitute that particular guess, without the homogeneous part, into the system equation. It probably doesn't matter to include the homogeneous part or not because it yields $0$ response. I mean, at least, this is what I know. However, after plugging into the system equation, the consistency achieved only if we make the substitution including the homogeneous part. This is the part I am specifically having hard time to understand. In general, it's not even done this way. Thank you for your time.

@LarsSmith: Please see my edit. Note that $y_h[n]$ satisfies the homogeneous DE for all $n$, but not $y_h[n]u[n]$. The latter only satisfies the homogeneous DE for $n\ge N$.

@LarsSmith: And if you plug $A_0\delta[n]$ into the DE (without the homogeneous solution) you immediately see that $A_0=0$, because you get a term $A_0\delta[n-2]$ without any match on the right-hand side (which is $\delta[n]-\delta[n-1]$).

Your edit is really helpful to see how it works including homogeneous part, thank you. However, regarding your last comment, even though you get $A_0 = 0$ and/or $B_0 = 0$ for $A_0\delta[n]$ and $A_0\delta[n] + B_0\delta[n-1]$, respectively, the equation itself isn't consistent like that one you did by including the homogeneous part. If it is not included, then we end up with something like $0 = \delta[n] - \delta[n-1]$, if I am not mistaken, of course. I think I need to ponder on your second last comment. Did you mean $n \ge 0$? Because for $n\ge0$, it seems $y_h[n]u[n]=y_h[n]$.

@LarsSmith: I meant $n\ge N$, look at the example in my edit. Only for $n\ge 2$ do you get all delayed components of the homogeneous solution, which makes sure that they add up to zero. And as for you comment on consistency, of course the equation isn't consistent because $A_0\delta[n]$ isn't a solution of the DE, but you can see that $A_0$ must be zero. Consistency is achieved by adding $y_h[n]u[n]$. I think your misunderstanding lies in the fact that you think in terms of particular and homogeneous solutions. But we don't have a particular solution.

So it means that unless the forced solution is guaranteed to exist, this method should be avoided, or to be safer, should be applied with the inclusion of the homogeneous solution. I will try it with the cases where $M \ge N$. Thank you so much for your time. Irrelevantly, in the meantime, I've been listening to your music and I think it's absolutely fantastic. Thank you, kind regards.

Thanks, yes, I'd say with the inclusion of the homogeneous solution, because the combination of possible impulses plus the causal part of the homogeneous solution according to $(3)$ is in fact a particular solution.

Oh! So I was right about my "random comment" all along? The causal homogeneous solution does contain a component of the forced response. Sounds like that comment wasn't so random :D Thank you so very much! Kind regards.
